# Composite pattern for file and folder structure with parent reference in C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I'm currently struggling with the implementation of a set of file system classes. I guess this calls for the composite pattern if I'm not mistaken. So I set up the following classes:

An abstract class `Node` which has a reference to its parent folder and two classes `Folder` and `File` that implement `Node`. A folder contains a collection of all its children and methods to add and remove children.

The thing is, I can't figure out how to implement all the methods properly. In all the examples I have seen there is no reference to the parent in the children. How can the `AddChild` method ensure that the child's parent reference is set correctly? I solved that by checking whether `child.Parent` has already been set to the folder or it throws an `ArgumentException`. The matter is further complicated by the fact that `AddChild` might also throw an exception like `DuplicateNameException` or something. So my methods look like this now:

```
File.AddTo(Folder folder) {
    this.Parent = folder;
    try {
        folder.AddChild(this);
    } catch {
        this.Parent = null;
        throw;
    }
}

Folder.AddChild(Node child)
{
    if(child.Parent != this)
        throw new ArgumentException(...);
    ...
}
```

Now I have this ugly `AddTo` method and cannot do something like `someFolder.AddChild(new File(...))`. I wonder how it was implemented with `ListViewItem` for instance. There I can just do `someListView.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(...))`.

My solution works, but I'm not convinced that it's the right way to do this. Maybe someone has a better solution or can point me to a good example. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: Minimal full class definitions below.

```
abstract class Node
{
    public Folder Parent { get; protected set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public Node(string name) {
        Parent = null;
        Name = name;
    }
}

class Folder : Node {
    private Dictionary<string, Node> _children;

    public Folder(string name) : base(name) {
        // Other initializations here...
    }

    public void AddChild(Node child) {
        if(child is Folder)
            ((Folder)child).Parent = this; // Damn, doesn't work for files!!!
        else if(child.Parent != this)
            throw new ArgumentException();

        if(_children.ContainsKey(child.Name))
            throw new DuplicateNameException();

        _children[child.Name] = child;
    }
}

class File : Node {
    public File(string name) : base(name) {
        // Other initializations here...
    }

    public void AddTo(Folder folder) {
        Parent = folder;
        try {
            folder.AddChild(this);
        } catch {
            Parent = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the definitions you've currently got for File, Folder and Node?

Answer (score 1):

How about doing it the other way around:

```
Folder.AddChild(Node child) 
{
   child.Parent = this;
   this._children.Add(child); // or what ever your doing to store the children
   ...
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was about to write, and I can't figure out why the AddTo method needed!

Comment: This would require `Parent` to be publicly accessible. Then anyone could just do `someNode.Parent = nonsense`

Comment: that's correct but as expressed in the question, Parent is already a public or protected member of node, so both file and folder would have access to it, right?

Comment: @Jaime - in the question, the Parent could be a property with a public getter and private/protected setter, it's not clear really - that's why I asked the OP to provide the class definitions.

Comment: @Jaime/KazR: As far as I know that's not correct, since `File` is not a `Folder`, a folder cannot change a file's parent unless it was public

Comment: @user1047771 - hmm, but the example you've provided only shows the Parent being set on 'this', hence the inference that it could be private/protected.

Comment: @user1047771 that's correct, you will have to expose Parent as a public member (or a SetParent method), for this approach to work, may be you have to ask yourself if you really need to have a two-way reference (child->parent->child) if you don't want to expose the Parent property

Comment: @KazR, you're right more clarification in the full Node definition is needed to see if this works :)

Comment: @Jaime: I'm just trying to write fool-proof code here. If I make the parent setter public, someone might try to move a node by setting its parent to a different node and thereby break the data structure. On the other hand, if there was no parent reference someone might also add the same node to different parents. (That's not the reason why I need the parent though.)

Comment: @user1047771 wild thought, how about making the Parent property readonly with something like `Parent {set { if(_parent != null) throw new InvalidOperationException("My dad is my dad... no adoptions here!"); _parent = value; } }` this would prevent you from legitimately moving files though, you would have to copy and remove

Comment: @Jaime There is still the question when to initially assign the parent. Someone might try something like `n = new File(...); n.Parent = someFolder;`. I guess I shouldn't try to protect my code from itself. As pointed out in Cheesos answer, I could use `internal`. That would at least prevent misuse from outside the assembly.

Comment: @user1047771 how about making the association in the constructor of the File/Folder `new File(parentFolder);` then you don't have to expose anything

Answer (score 1):

If you're adding a child to the parent, that should be done through a method on parent.  Parent can then confirm/validate its own state and that its preconditions are satisfied.  It's not up to a node to figure out whether its parent is valid -- let the parent do that.

So, by way of code, you have something like:

```
public class Node
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public abstract void Add(Node child);
    protected abstract void CreateOnDisk();
}

public class File
{
    public override void Add(Node child)
    {
         //No op, since you can't add a child to a file
    }

    protected override void CreateOnDisk()
    {
        File.Create(this.Name);
    }
}

public class Directory
{
    public override void Add(Node child)
    {
        child.Name = Path.Combine(this.Name, child.Name);
        child.CreateOnDisk();
    }

    protected override CreateOnDisk()
    {
        Directory.Create(this.Name);
    }
}
```

I just freelanced a bit off the top of my head, but that's to give an idea.  I really think there's no need to keep track of your parent, and I think that's going to turn out in the end to be a fairly cumbersome solution.

Comment: Er, problem with no tests/VS is that the little things get away.  You'd need to take this concept and clean up the use of the Name property a bit (that may need to be two properties - path and name).

Comment: I was planning on using the parent reference for access control resolution, i.e. if an operation is performed on a node, it checks its access control list--if it doesn't find a match, it checks its parent's list and so on... Parent also helps to avoid `folder1.Add(node); folder2.Add(node);` <- oops, not a tree anymore

Comment: Why wouldn't the result of that be adding the file/directory represented by "node" to each folder?  If I create "temp.txt" in C:\dir1 and in C:\dir2, I have two different text files -- not a symbolic link in one and a text file in the other.

Comment: That's true for the files in the underlying file system you created in `CreateOnDisk`. The data structure itself, however, is not a tree anymore. Also `Add` changes the node's path. If you traverse folder1 now, hat node would give you the path to folder2. In any case, my goal was not to superimpose some data structure on the existing file system. It was more of a general question on how to avoid having a public setter for the parent.

Answer (score 1):

When I implement bidirectional associations, I usually move all association maintenance to one of the sides. In this case, I'd chose Folder.

```
public abstract class Node
{
    public Folder Parent { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public abstract long Size { get; }
}

public class File : Node
{        
    private long _size;

    public override long Size
    {
        get { return _size; }
    }

    public void AddTo(Folder folder)
    {
        folder.Add(this);
    }

    public void RemoveFrom(Folder folder)
    {
        folder.Remove(this);
    }
}

public class Folder : Node
{
    private List<Node> _children = new List<Node>();

    public void Add(Node node)
    {
        if (node.Parent == this)
            return; // already a child of this folder

        _children.Add(node);
        node.Parent = this;
    }

    public void Remove(Node node)
    {
        if (node.Parent != this)
            return; // not a child of this folder

        _children.Remove(node);
        node.Parent = null;
    }

    public override long Size
    {
        get { return _children.Sum(node => node.Size); }
    }
}
```

PS try to eliminate bidirectional association, it adds lot of headache.

UPDATE
With unidirectional association you have simple code, without ugly Folder field in Node class (I hate when base class depends on its child). Also no headache with adding/removing files.

```
public abstract class Node
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public abstract long Size { get; }
}

public class File : Node
{        
    private long _size;

    public override long Size
    {
        get { return _size; }
    }
}

public class Folder : Node
{
    private List<Node> _children = new List<Node>();

    public void Add(Node node)
    {
        if (_children.Contains(node))
            return;

        _children.Add(node);
    }

    public void Remove(Node node)
    {
        if (!_children.Contains(node))
            return;

        _children.Remove(node);
    }        

    public override long Size
    {
        get { return _children.Sum(node => node.Size); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`AddChild()` is a method on the parent.

Thinking about the purpose of the method, and your desire to maintain a reference to the parent in the child, you need to expose a property *on the child* that can be set by the parent, presumably in the `AddChild` method.

```
public abstract class Node 
{
    private Node parent;

    internal void SetParent(Node parent)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}

public class Folder : Node
{
    void AddChild(Node child) 
    {
        this.children.Add(child);
        child.SetParent(this); // or, you could use a C# Property
    }
}


public class File : Node
{
}
```

The child knows how to establish its parent; the parent knows how to adopt a child.

Comment: This won't work as written - the child.SetParent isn't accessible from AddChild in Folder.

Comment: oops - I didn't mean `protected`, I meant `internal`.  I've fixed it.